# Console Log Stream information using ffmpeg node.js

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, video-streaming, console-application, console.log

I have created a work application that links in room encoders to live stream onto Facebook, Twitter and Youtube. I am wondering as to how to properly log the stream quality on the CMD. Below are snippets of the code and where I think the logic should be to properly pull the stream quality and display it in the cmd:

Pushing Stream:

```
    if (req.query.french_facebook) {
  var streamComplete = req.query.fb_fre_streamURL + req.query.fb_fre_streamKey;
  temp = checkValidity('Facebook', 'French', req.query.fb_fre_streamURL, req.query.fb_fre_streamKey, status);
  status = temp[0];
  valid = temp[1];
  if (valid == true) {
    var command = `ffmpeg -re -i ${inputURL2('French',req.query.fb_fre_venue)} -c:v copy -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -x264-params keyint=60:scenecut=0 -strict -2 -f flv "${streamComplete}"`;
    var process = nodeCmd.run(command);
    createStream(req.query.username, 'Facebook', 'French', req.query.fb_fre_streamKey, process.pid);
  } else {
    console.error("ERROR: unable to create stream");
  }
}
```

App initialization:

```
    var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var fs = require('fs');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

If there is anything I am not making clear please let me know

Comment: What do you mean by " pull the stream quality"

Comment: The stream's bitrate per frame, it is defined as the data of the ffmpeg stream